# File not found exception in JAR file

Tags: java

I am getting the file not found exception in jar files. But i have the jar file in the path.

Comment: so in you jar file you have a file called com/standardandpoors/integration/schema/idm/"http://sqpx.dev.spratingsvpc.com:21111/sst/IdmService?WSDL"??????
Looks a bit wierd to me

Comment: looks like some problem to me in here `com.standardandpoors.integration.schema.idm.IdmService.(IdmService.java:55)` or either the way the jar isn't specified in the project build path.

Comment: You should check if you have the latest versions of the jars and also remove any duplicate versions for the same jar